# Database stored language with vuejs and i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, vue-i18n

I'm working on a vuejs application (I'm quite new in it and still learning)
I try to make this application multi language. The objective is when you arrive on the login page (non logged user) the app will automatically take your browser language. At the moment you log-in, the application will have as a locale the one specified in your profile.

But of course for me nothing change when I log in.

Let me show what I tried:

I have a user with the language "fr" in the database and I use a language "en" on my browser.

I did this in my i18n.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages() {
    const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
    const messages = {}
    locales.keys().forEach(key => {
        const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
        if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
            const locale = matched[1]
            messages[locale] = locales(key)
        }
    })
    return messages
}

export const selected_locale = navigator.language.split('-')[0]

export default new VueI18n({
    locale: selected_locale || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
    fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
    messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

And I import in in my main.js

Than in my store/index.js I have:

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import i18n from 'vue-i18n'
import Vue from 'vue'
import {selected_locale} from "../i18n";

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        token: '',
        locale: selected_locale,
        user: {},
    },
    mutations: {
        updateLocale(state, newLocale) {
            state.locale = newLocale
        }
    },
    actions: {
        changeLocale({commit}, newLocale) {
            i18n.locale = newLocale // important!
            commit('updateLocale', newLocale)
        }
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    modules: {}
})
```

Finally, in my login view I do this:

```js
          axios
            .post("/api/v1/token/login", formData)
            .then(response => {
              const token = response.data.auth_token
              this.$store.commit('setToken', token)
              axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token
              localStorage.setItem('token', token)
              this.$store.commit('setUser', response.data.user)
              localStorage.setItem('username', response.data.user.username)
              localStorage.setItem('user_id', response.data.user.id.toString())
              this.$store.dispatch('changeLocale', response.data.user.language)
              const toPath = this.$route.query.to || '/'
              this.$router.push(toPath)
            })
```

All the other parts (username etc) works well so I know I'm going through this "then" But it seems my translations are not caring about the change in my store.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: The scope of your question is just too large (and there is nothing wrong at first sight). Consider creating [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)